# Replace a file / image in File Manager?

Tags: file-manager

I think the answer to this is "no", but is there any way in File Manager to replace an uploaded image?

So if an image is used somewhere on the site, and we want to just replace it with a new one, we can just upload the new version, without needing to know what stylesheet or template file makes reference to it?  Seems like a basic request.  I guess the only other option is to delete the file and upload one with the same exact filename.

-jim

Answer (score 1):

If you have FTP access, you should just be able to overwrite the file on the server.  Anywhere it's referenced on the site then, should pick up the file.

Comment: Ok, yes, I guess that's a possible solution, however then I have to teach the editors how to use FTP, and where to put the files.